# capture regex group occurrence in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

i'm struggling with a regular expression that extract some groups from a string, but it only extract the last two groups either in javascript:

```
^{((\w+=[^=]+)\s*,\s*)*(\w+=[^=]+)}$
```

all i want is to get two part with an equal sign in the middle and after each group their is a comma

the strings:

```
{type='OGONE'} 

{type=['OGONE'], period=['2018','2019']}

{type=['OGONE'], period='2018', names=['yoeunes']}

{type='OGONE', period=['2018','2019'], names=['sara','hamza'], ages=[20, 21]}
```

https://regex101.com/r/lGgMfM/1

and Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just use something like `(\w+)=\[([^\][]*)]` to get all matches. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z7sqZz/1). Neither JS nor PHP support a capture stack for each capturing group. If you set a `+` or `*` quantifier to a capturing group, only the last capture will be kept in the capture group memory buffer. It is possible in .NET, Python PyPi regex module, but not PHP/JS.

Comment: No idea, what do you mean by "can i just edit the strings a little bit"?

Comment: sorry i was editing the question, for example if the group is like this:  type='OGONE'

Comment: Do you need it for PHP? Or really both? What works for PHP won't necessarily work for JS. This makes the question a bit too broad.

Comment: i want it mostly for JS, i can drop the php part

Comment: its like and "in" and "eq" operators

Comment: The regex101 link you provided explicitly tells you in the explanation: "A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration." This is expected behaviour. You should instead capture the whole thing, and then process the individual parts separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JS, you may use a regex like

```
(\w+)=(?:\[([^\][]*)]|'([^']*)')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ls2kPh/1).

**Details**

- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `=` - an equal sign
- `(?:\[([^\][]*)]|'([^']*)')` - either

  - `\[([^\][]*)]` - `[`, Group 2: any 0+ chars other than `[` and `]` and then `]`
  - `|` - or
  - `'([^']*)'` - `'`, Group 3: any 0+ chars other than `'`, `'`

A JS demo:

```js
var strs = ["{type='OGONE'}", "{type=['OGONE'], period=['2018','2019']}", "{type=['OGONE'], period='2018', names=['yoeunes']}", "{type='OGONE', period=['2018','2019'], names=['sara','hamza'], ages=[20, 21]}]"];
var rx = /(\w+)=(?:\[([^\][]*)]|'([^']*)')/g;
for (var s of strs) {
  var results=[], m;
  console.log("STRING:", s);
  while(m=rx.exec(s)) {
    if (m[2]) {
      results.push([m[1], m[2]]);
    } else {
      results.push([m[1], m[3]]);
    }
  }
  console.log("RESULTS:", results);
}
```

Comment: @yoeunes I was trying to enahnce it with further parsing Group 2 value, but I think you know the input format better. If you need help with that, drop a comment here.